# VSC vs Arduino IDE C++ compilation fail

Tags: c

Can you tell me about an error. I have scatch for arduino nano, this code compilation on Arduino IDE! But doesn't work on VSC **'ai0' was not declared in this scope  'ai1' was not declared in this scope**.

```
  
void setup() {
Serial.begin (9600);

pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); // internal pullup input pin 2 

pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); // internalเป็น pullup input pin 3
//Setting up interrupt
//A rising pulse from encodenren activated ai0(). AttachInterrupt 0 is DigitalPin nr 2 on moust Arduino.
attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING);
 
//B rising pulse from encodenren activated ai1(). AttachInterrupt 1 is DigitalPin nr 3 on moust Arduino.
attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);
}
 
void loop() {
// Send the value of counter
if( counter != temp ){
Serial.println (counter);
temp = counter;
}
}
 
void ai0() {
// ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 2 is going from LOW to HIGH
// Check pin 3 to determine the direction
if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
counter++;
}else{
counter--;
}
}
 
void ai1() {
// ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 3 is going from LOW to HIGH
// Check with pin 2 to determine the direction
if(digitalRead(2)==LOW) {
counter--;
}else{
counter++;
}
}``
```

Comment: The messages are quite clear: Provide a declaration (i.e. a prototype) for any function before you use it. Also do you compile as C or C++? Arduino is C++ but with VS Code it depends on what compiler commands you are using.

Comment: As you do not include any headers, I would expect way more similar messages.

Comment: Yes only in VSC #include <Arduino.h>

Comment: Arduino IDE inserts header silently by himself. To use another IDE, not tailored for ARDUINO, you must include the necessary headers.

Comment: Ok, which include?

Comment: The required headers for all external functions, types and macros that are used. For the error messages you showed us, there are no missing headers but only missing prototypes.

Comment: At least `#include <Arduino.h>`. You should have defined paths for headers.

Comment: I include **#include <Arduino.h>** in VSC, but receive this error  `'ai0' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Use your favorite search tool and look for the missing declaration in the include directory of your Arduino installation. The header file containing it should be the next to include.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I search problem, in VSC was like that **void ai0** and **void ai1** above **void setup**

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void ai0() {
// ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 2 is going from LOW to HIGH
// Check pin 3 to determine the direction
if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
counter++;
}else{
counter--;
}
}
 
void ai1() {
// ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 3 is going from LOW to HIGH
// Check with pin 2 to determine the direction
if(digitalRead(2)==LOW) {
counter--;
}else{
counter++;
}

void setup() {
Serial.begin (9600);

pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); // internal pullup input pin 2 

pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); // internalเป็น pullup input pin 3
//Setting up interrupt
//A rising pulse from encodenren activated ai0(). AttachInterrupt 0 is DigitalPin nr 2 on moust Arduino.
attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING);
 
//B rising pulse from encodenren activated ai1(). AttachInterrupt 1 is DigitalPin nr 3 on moust Arduino.
attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);
}
 
void loop() {
// Send the value of counter
if( counter != temp ){
Serial.println (counter);
temp = counter;
}
}
```